# Exception class $C0000005 with message 'c0000005 ACCESS_VIOLATION'

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-xe7

I have created a WSDL service using RAD Studio (C++ Builder) and it works fine tested it using Microsoft Visual Studio . now i am trying to use this in as application in RAD studio (C++).

```
static const char* defWSDL= "http://localhost:8080/wsdl/IAndroidService";
  static const char* defURL = "http://localhost:8080/soap/IAndroidService";
  static const char* defSvc = "IAndroidServiceservice";
  static const char* defPrt = "IAndroidServicePort";
  if (addr=="")
    addr = useWSDL ? defWSDL : defURL;
  Soaphttpclient::THTTPRIO* rio = HTTPRIO ? HTTPRIO : new Soaphttpclient::THTTPRIO(0);
  if (useWSDL) {
    rio->WSDLLocation = addr;
    rio->Service = defSvc;
    rio->Port = defPrt;
  } else {
    rio->URL = addr;
  }
```

No matter what i do i get an exception at either 
rio->WSDLLocation = addr;

or

rio->URL = addr;

and here is the exception

```
Exception class $C0000005 with message 'c0000005 ACCESS_VIOLATION'
```

I am calling the service like this

```
Soaphttpclient::THTTPRIO* riod;
bool useWSDL = True;
_di_IAndroidService service = NS_IAndroidService::GetIAndroidService(useWSDL,"",riod);
```

Can someone please advise.

Thanks

Comment: `addr = useWSDL ? defWSDL : defURL;` looks like it is missing a `=`.

Comment: In addition, I would recommend that you use `if (addr[0] == 0)` instead of `if (addr == ""`), since `addr` might be pointing to an empty string which has a different address than that of the literal string `""`.

Comment: @barakmanos: that depends on what `addr` is declared as. What you say would be true for a `char*` but not for a `(Ansi/Unicode/Wide)String`, a `std::(w)string()`, etc.

Comment: @Ali: I'm going to take a shot in the dark and guess that `HTTPRIO` is not NULL so `?:` is returning `HTTPRIO`, but it is otherwise not initialized to a valid object, so you would be trying to access properties via an invalid pointer, hence the AV.

Comment: @Ali: BTW: `Soaphttpclient::THTTPRIO* rio = HTTPRIO ? HTTPRIO : new Soaphttpclient::THTTPRIO(0);` is a memory leak waiting to happen on desktop platforms if `HTTPRIO` is NULL.

Comment: Where is `HTTPRIO` assigned? and what is it assigned?'